# Insert data with to_date into a table

Tags: sql, shell, awk

I have many files(.rules) having data as below in each file & delimited by "|"

```
dummy test rule1|2009599|20100730
dummy test rule2|2009600|20100730
dummy test rule3|2009601|20100730
```

And I am trying to insert above data into a table (with to_date), but getting error as:

> awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file `2009599' for reading (No
>   such file or directory)

Comment: Please make your question more informative: what commands do you run exactly; why do you use awk; etc.